# C++ cout like function, which writes data to file (logging)

Tags: c++, logging, cout

I have been this on days and I think I am missing something simple.
This is how cout works:

```
cout << "Testing" << 5;
```

Note that inputs can be anything, string, int etc. Instead of cout I want to use Log, and catch all of the data and write it to file. This is wanted:

```
log << "Testing" << 5;
```

Closest I have gotten.
Header:

```
class LogFile {
public:
    void write(std::string input);
    int operator<<(const char u[100]);
    int operator<<(const int u);
};
```

C++

```
int LogFile::operator<<(const char u[100]) {
    std::string s;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << u;
    s = ss.str();
    this->write(s);
    return 0;
};
int LogFile::operator<<(const int u) {
    std::string s;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << u;
    s = ss.str();
    this->write(s);
    return 0;
};
```

Code which is ran (only "Testing" is written, int is ignored):

```
LogFile log;
log << "Testing" << 5;
```

Goal is to write a function which mimics cout, but instead of printing, data is written to file. Any advise or help is appreciated!

Comment: We already have `std::clog`. You can redirect its output.

Comment: @chris, or even redirect cout.

Comment: Just return a reference to the object on which `operator<<` is called (the `LogFile`-object), change the return-type appropriately and you can chain output-operations like with `cout`. On the other hand, why even bother with writing your own logging-utility, when everything you need is already provided?

Comment: "Goal is to write a function which mimics cout, but instead of printing, data is written to file" - Any ofstream object?

Comment: @latedeveloper They may want to format the log messages or anything before writing to the file.

Comment: @YSC generally yes, but not in this particular case. So while educationalyl it might be interesting, author might just be missing out on ofstream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a templated `operator<<`:

```
#include <sstream>
struct Log
{
    void write(std::string const& s);

    template<class T>
    Log& operator<<(T const& msg)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << msg;
        write(ss.str());
        return *this;
    }
};
```

This would be a possible usage:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Log log;
    log << 8;
    log << "Hello, " << "World!";
    std::string msg("plop");
    log << msg;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0c4c4dd41e96d64)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. This certainly pushed me in the right direction.
Any ideas on how to collect several inputs and then write to file, instead of writing them separately. Right now, this (log << "Hello, " << "World!";) writes on 2 lines, it should write on 1 line.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question as asked (although the goal would be better served using different approach):

Your `operator <<` return `0` - an integral type. When you call `operator<<` on the return value, you end up calling built in bitwise shift operator, which just bitwise shifts 0 by 5, discarding the result.

You would see compilation error if you'd try to `log << "Testing" << "Testing";`

To fix the code, your `operator<<` should return a reference to `*this` - the object of type `LogFile`.

Answer (score 1):

"function which mimics cout" -- `cout` is **not** a function. It is an **object**. What you're trying to do is to create an **object** that can be used with stream inserters and writes to a log file. `std::ofstream` may be of use here.